# 3G connection with ModemManager and Netplan connect and disconnect immediatly

Tags: ubuntu, networking, modem, netplan, modem-manager

I have a problem with an old 3G modem (Telit HE910), the connection is made via Netplan and ModemManager.
The modem is recognized correctly when Ubuntu starts and the SIM is also recognized without problems.
The strange thing is that it seems that the connection is established but then immediately the modem disconnects.
I tried starting ModemManager in debug mode but I'm not very expert with modems to understand where the problem actually is.

Netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3:                 # eth0 - Maintenance
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
      addresses:
      - 172.0.0.10/24
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 172.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 1
      match:
        name: enp3*
      set-name: enp3
    enp4:                 # eth1 - External modem
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
      match:
        name: enp4*
      set-name: enp4
  modems:
    telit:                # Internal modem
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      apn: iliad
      auto-config: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 900
      match:
        name: ttyACM*
      set-name: mobile
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
      access-points:      # Required for wifis
        "empty":
          password: ""
```

ModemManager logs:

```
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.761616] [modem0/bearer0] connection through a plain serial AT port: ttyACM0
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.761825] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 5 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.762137] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 4 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.762428] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'ATD*99***3#<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.796882] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '<CR><LF>CONNECT<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.797202] [modem0/bearer0] setting flow control in ttyACM0: rts-cts
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.797369] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] enabling RTS/CTS flow control
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.797575] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] flow control settings updated to rts-cts
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.797780] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] port now connected
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.798010] [modem0/bearer0] connected
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.798634] [modem0/bearer0] PPP is required for connection, will ignore disconnection reports
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750117.798836] [modem0] state changed (registered -> connected)
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750117.800684] [modem0] simple connect state (8/8): all done
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.801266] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 3 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.836536] [modem0] user request to disconnect modem (all bearers)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.839942] [modem0] user request to disconnect modem (all bearers)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.850015] [modem0] user request to connect modem
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.859771] [modem0/bearer0] disconnecting...
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750117.860051] [modem0] state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.861365] [modem0/bearer0] sending PDP context deactivation in secondary port...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.861621] [modem0/ttyACM3/at] device open count is 2 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.862099] [modem0/ttyACM3/at] --> 'AT+CGACT=0,3<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.888064] [modem0/ttyACM3/at] <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.888482] [modem0/bearer0] reopening data port ttyACM0...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.888661] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] reopening port (3)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.888796] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 2 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.888921] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 1 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.889047] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 0 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.889250] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] closing serial port...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.889431] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] port now disconnected
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.892280] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] serial port closed
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.892472] [modem0/ttyACM3/at] device open count is 1 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750117.892880] [modem0] simple connect started...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893018] [modem0]    profile ID: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893149] [modem0]    PIN: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893266] [modem0]    operator ID: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893376] [modem0]    allowed roaming: yes
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893487] [modem0]    APN: iliad
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893596] [modem0]    APN type: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893707] [modem0]    IP family: ipv4v6
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893828] [modem0]    allowed authentication: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.893948] [modem0]    user: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.894068] [modem0]    password: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750117.894184] [modem0]    multiplex: unspecified
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750117.894341] [modem0] simple connect state (4/8): wait to get fully enabled
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.893991] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] opening serial port...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.896308] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] setting up baudrate: 57600
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.896488] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] no flow control explicitly requested for device
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.896831] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 1 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.896970] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 2 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.897117] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 3 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.897306] [modem0/bearer0] flashing data port ttyACM0...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.897691] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.898171] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 2 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.898562] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] running init sequence...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.899053] [modem0/bearer0] PDP disconnection already sent
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.899235] [modem0/bearer0] disconnected
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750118.899435] [modem0] state changed (disconnecting -> registered)
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750118.899820] [modem0] simple connect state (5/8): register
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.900457] [modem0] already registered automatically in network '22250', automatic registration not launched...
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750118.902789] [modem0/bearer0] connection #1 finished: duration 1s, tx: 0 bytes, rx: 0 bytes
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750118.903778] [modem0] simple connect state (6/8): bearer
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.905370] [modem0] creating new bearer...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.905609] [modem0] creating broadband bearer in broadband modem...
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.906852] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 3 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750118.910141] [modem0] simple connect state (7/8): connect
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.910928] [modem0/bearer1] connecting...
ModemManager[1696]: <info>  [1662750118.911186] [modem0] state changed (registered -> connecting)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.913608] [modem0/bearer1] launching 3GPP connection attempt
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.913857] [modem0] set profile state (1/8): check format
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.914074] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 4 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.914341] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 3 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750118.915863] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'ATE0<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750119.795226] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750120.795152] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750121.180951] [modem0/ttyACM3/at] <-- '<CR><LF>+CIEV: signal,2<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750121.181451] [modem0] signal quality updated (28)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750121.795367] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750122.510824] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 4 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750122.511330] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'ATV1<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750122.795777] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750123.795760] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750124.796161] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <warn>  [1662750125.510748] [modem0] port ttyACM0 timed out 2 consecutive times
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750125.511081] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'AT+CMEE=1<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750125.796557] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750126.797186] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750127.797395] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&,\2070d}'}"}(}"\214\165~'
ModemManager[1696]: <warn>  [1662750128.511090] [modem0] port ttyACM0 timed out 3 consecutive times
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.511364] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'ATX4<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.931528] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '<CR><LF>NO CARRIER<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.931900] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] operation failure: 1 (No carrier)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.932274] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'AT&C1<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.938206] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '<CR><LF>+CIEV: signal,2<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.938646] [modem0] signal quality updated (28)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.948414] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.949130] [modem0] +CGDCONT format details for PDP type 'ipv4v6': minimum 1, maximum 5
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.949320] [modem0] context definition format: minimum 1, maximum 5
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.949464] [modem0] set profile state (2/8): list before
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.949675] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 5 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.949897] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 4 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.950154] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'AT+CCLK?<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.975347] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.975784] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '+CCLK: "00/01/01,00:32:47+08"<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.976535] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 3 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750128.977418] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'AT+CGDCONT?<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.003874] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '<CR><LF>+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","web.omnitel.it","",0,0<CR><LF>+CGDCONT: 2,"IP","iliad","",0,0<CR><LF>+CGDCONT: 3,"IPV4V6","iliad","",0,0<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.004954] [modem0] set profile state (3/8): select profile (best)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.005130] [modem0] found exact context at profile 3
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.005258] [modem0] reusing profile '3'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.005408] [modem0] set profile state (4/8): check activated profile
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.005614] [modem0] checking if profile with id '3' is already activated...=
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.005813] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 4 (open)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.006106] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 3 (close)
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.006645] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] --> 'AT+CGACT?<CR>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.032246] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.032967] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] <-- '+CGACT: 1,0<CR><LF>+CGACT: 2,0<CR><LF>+CGACT: 3,0<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.034446] [modem0] profile '3' is not activated
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.034826] [modem0] set profile state (6/8): profile already stored
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.035450] [modem0] set profile state (8/8): all done
ModemManager[1696]: <debug> [1662750129.036522] [modem0/ttyACM0/at] device open count is 4 (open)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

After several days I finally arrived at a solution. Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS does not include the `ppp` and `pppoe` packages, which are necessary for the Telit HE910.
I arrived at this solution by removing all Netplan configs and using only NetworkManager. Trying to connect manually with `nmcli c up mycon` showed a fairly generic error, which however was related to the ppp package.

After installing the packages I was also able to reactivate the Netplan configuration without problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is no surprise!

Vodafone Italia Omnitel, which seems to be your mobile network operator (even if your APN seems to be controlled by iliad, is this some roaming agreement?), shutdown the 3G network in 2021. So, no connection can be established to it.

So, unless you want to continue using your modem for 2G (or, rather, 2.5 to 2.75 G, i.e. GPRS or EDGE) service, and instruct your system to accept that, and also have a subscription that allows for that, it's electronic waste.

Comment: In my area the 3G Iliad network currently works because if I try with my smartphone by setting the network to 3G only I navigate correctly, in fact the APN set is for the Iliad network.

Comment: however, your modem clearly receives a configuration message that informs your system to use the vodafone APN, and vodafone doesn't do 3G anymore: `<-- '<CR><LF>+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","web.omnitel.it","",0,0<CR><LF>+CGDCONT: 2,"IP","iliad","",0,0<CR><LF>+CGDCONT: 3,"IPV4V6","iliad","",0,0<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'`

Comment: OK, what I don't understand is why if the config in netplan is configured like this:

```
modems:
     telit: # Internal modem
       dhcp4: true
       optional: true
       apn: iliad
```

continues to take the old Vodafone configuration, how can I reset it?

Comment: it's not "taking" old configuration, it gets that from the network, usually! but it could only get that through a connection, so I'm just as confused

Comment: Ok I've found an old netplan config with the apn, now I've deleted it and rebooted and in the logs i see only the Iliad config but the result is the same:

 --> 'AT+CGDCONT?<CR>'
 <-- '<CR><LF>'
 <-- '+CGDCONT: 3,"IPV4V6","iliad","",0,0<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
 --> 'ATD*99***3#<CR>'
 <-- '<CR><LF>CONNECT<CR><LF>'
setting flow control in ttyACM0: rts-cts
enabling RTS/CTS flow control
flow control settings updated to rts-cts
port now connected
connected

user request to disconnect modem (all bearers)
user request to connect modem
disconnecting...

thanks for your support!

Comment: I've found another log, I don't know if could be related:

signal quality updated (57)
<-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&}*_\165\178}'}"}(}"y\170~'
<-- '~\255}#\192!}!}!} }8}"}&} } } } }#}$\192#}%}&}*_\165\178}'}"}(}"y\170~'
loading signal quality...
device open count is 4 (open)
port ttyACM0 timed out 3 consecutive times
--> 'ATX4<CR>'
<-- '<CR><LF>NO CARRIER<CR><LF>'
operation failure: 1 (No carrier)

Comment: is the `AT+CGACT?` response still the same, i.e., all networks disabled?

Comment: relatively normal that there's no carrier before one gives the modem a chance to search for a network, that's why it's asked to enable autonomous signal detection reports exactly in the next message.

Comment: AT+CGACT? produce the same message: +CGACT: 3,0<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>

Comment: what about the 2 other networks which were there before?

Comment: I completely reset all Netplan configurations and started from 0

Comment: If I understand correctly, I now have a config with CID 3 but it is disabled, correct?

--> 'AT+CGDCONT?<CR>'
<-- '+CGDCONT: 3,"IPV4V6","iliad","",0,0<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'

--> 'AT+CGACT?<CR>'
<-- '+CGACT: 3.0<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'

Comment: yep, that's what it looks like

Comment: can I just enable it with this command?
AT+CGACT=1.3

Comment: I don't understand the reason but if I launch the command AT+CGACT=1.3 and re-reading the value it changes to +CGACT: 3.1 but then after a few seconds it goes back to deactivated +CGACT: 3.0

Comment: I can only guess, but it might try to connect, but then gets rejected?

Comment: I noticed that the modem has 2 AT ports:
ports: ttyACM0 (at), ttyACM1 (ignored), ttyACM2 (ignored), tyACM3 (at), ttyACM4 (ignored), ttyACM5 (ignored)

the activation command comes from ttyACM0 while the deactivation command comes from ttyACM3

Comment: Finally i've solved... it was only a problem with missing ppp & pppoe packages on Ubuntu 22.04lts distribution... thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cristian glad to hear that! Could you put what you've done into an answer post to your question? Just a small quick one for future readers